# Error ITMS-90047 iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, application-loader

I'm trying to upload my application (build in Xamarin Studio) via Application Loader (version 3.0.0)  to iTunes Connect but I keep getting Error ITMS-90047 (see screenshot).

[image]

I've submitted previous versions of the application to iTunes Connect (last was 6 days ago) without a problem (the 64bit warning was there but currently I'm using iTunes Connect just for beta testing so it's not a problem).

Here is my .plist file:

[image]

I've tried doing clean build, deleting everything from bin directory. Nothing helps. Not even google.

I'd be very grateful for any help cause I'm stuck.

Comment: The 64 bit support requirement is just a warning and not preventing the upload. Has anything changed in your iTunesMetadata.plist from the previous version that was successfully submitted?

Comment: It didn't change at all, that's the problem.

Comment: Answered same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32164242/455225

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have exactly the same problem.

You can try delete this plist, it works for me.

1. Unzip your ipa
2. Go to destination folder and compress "Payload" folder
3. Rename it to some_name.ipa
4. Upload that ipa

Comment: In fact, you can skip 3 step and upload zip

Comment: Since the app loader won't allow an an ipa with an itunesMetaData.plist file anymore, Xamarin should stop including this file in their IPA creation process.

Comment: OH, and I just archived, then went into the archive (it's just a Package), and found the iTunesMetadata files (it in Products -> applications -> your.ipa usually), deleted it, and it submitted fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below row in your plist file

> Application requires iPhone environment to YES.

I was having a issue with ipa earlier where i was able to create an ipa but was not installing on device.  I recently upgraded to XCode 6.2 and build ipa.

Comment: @maddy i was referring to the error not the warning... for warning arm64 needs to be added in build settings of valid architecture..     Please think before down voting on a answer, previliege is given to be used cautionly. I am not saying my answer is right but it solved the problem for me that why i am sharing what i achieved, this may be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin fixed this issue for applications with 64-bit support.