# ITMS-90047 Disallowed paths ("iTunesMetadata.plist")

Tags: ios, xamarin, app-store

I am getting the error when trying to submit my `Xamarin` application for review for the AppStore.

[image]

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

- Unzip your ipa
- Go to destination folder and compress "Payload" folder
- Rename it to some_name.ipa
- Upload that ipa

remove iTunesArtwork and iTunesArtwork@2x from the project (if any)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:
[Xamarin forum: "Disallowed paths ( "iTunesMetadata.plist" ) found at ..." when submitting to App Store](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/40388/disallowed-paths-itunesmetadata-plist-found-at-when-submitting-to-app-store)

I think the "Sign and Distribute" in Xamarin Studio fixes the issue.